# Is it safe to modify golang Http Transport while requests are in flight?

Tags: http, go

I have an application which rotates through proxies on a per request basis.

Currently I have some code which is:

```
func (mon *Monitor) MassUrlRetrieve(n int, url string) (respBytes []byte) {
    funnel := make(chan []byte)
    go ProductRetrieveTimeout(TIMEOUT_RETRIEVE_URL, funnel)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        go mon.WrapGetUrlToChannel(funnel, url)
    }
    return <- funnel
}
```

which basically sends off multiple requests and returns the first one to respond/ timeout if none respond in a timely manner.

In `WrapGetUrlToChannel` I create a new proxy url are assign it to `mon`'s `client.tr.Proxy`.

My question is - is it safe to modify the transport of the client while requests are in flight? Or to be safe should I have a different transport and client for each proxy to make sure they do not interfere?

Comment: The surest way to know is to run some tests with the race detector on. But just intuitively, it sounds dangerous (which you probably agree with since you're asking the question).

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea that was an option available to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the race detector it definitely showed that I shouldn't have been modifying the transport. In the end I decided on rotating *http.Transport around instead of proxies, and using unique clients when making concurrent requests.

Thanks to @Flimzy

Comment: do you still remember what do you mean by "rotating *http.Transport" - did you use the same client and just update the transport when "NOT" making concurrent requests. Thanks!